# Is there a way to remove attributes from an inherited property?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Is it possible to remove attributes from inherited properties?  I thought that by using the **new** keyword I could do so...

```
 public class Person
 {
     [Required]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string LastName { get; set; }
 }

 public class Employee : Person
 {
     [Required]
     public string JobTitle { get; set; }

     public new string FirstName { get; set; }
 }
```

... but this doesnt work at all.  This surprises me because the **new** is specifically there to hide inherited members.

Comment: On what basis do you think it does not work?

Comment: @Ben: I tried it.  I have a real project where it doesnt work.  I created a simple test project to verify it without lots code interfering and it still doesnt work. Both projects are asp.net mvc2. In both cases the "hidden" property still comes up as required.

Comment: Well, the hidden property `base.FirstName` IS marked required.  The new property `Employee.FirstName` is not required.  I don't use mvc2 so I can't help you any further.

Comment: I know you didn't specify in you're question, but if you are using Entity Framework, then the Fluent API takes priority. What this means is that in your ModelBuilder, you can do something like `modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(s => s.FirstName)              .IsOptional();` Is you are using EF please write it in your Q so I can make a proper answer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Employee class now has 2 FirstName properties, one of them is still  [Required] ...

Direct answer: No, you cannot remove attributes for as far as I know. That would violate the substitution principle. When an Employee IS-A Person then the properties of Person.FirstName apply.

And: the `new` keyword here *only* serves to suppress the 'X is hiding base class member..' warning. It has no effect whatsoever on the semantics of your code.